# OctoberCMS does updated plugin works in un-updated software

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

After updating the OctoberCMS software in backend I have figured an issue in my plugin, that is jquery's ajaxError method does not work accordingly. Since some new ajax methods were introduced by octobercms team and the old ajax methods were deprecated, I have updated the code in java scripts of my plugin. Now the plugin works perfectly. Even though I have fixed the issue what my doubt is when I place this updated plugin in market place does it cause a bug for the **user** who **download** this **updated plugin** to their **un-updated software**

Comment: you can ask here https://github.com/octobercms/october/issues and/or https://octobercms.com/forum/chan/october-helpsupport as well. This are their support forums.

Answer (score 0):

October is built such that users cannot update individual plugins without also updating October itself. Thus, if your new plugin version relies on a new **stable** build of October, it is safe to release it as any users that have an older build will be forced to update to the most recent October build before they can update to the latest version of your plugin.

This of course assumes that your plugin is distributed through the marketplace.

Answer (score 0):

To make sure of that, you can install a fresh copy of octoberCMS which will not be the latest updated software then install your updated plugin on it and see the result yourself.

And I can guarantee it will work with no problems neither the software is updated or not .